# How to pass data to another page using jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

What am I doing wrong ? I have jquery var which is storing data, i'm then sending this data to functions.php. But i'm not getting any results from the functions.php page. Any suggestions ?

```
var data = "&insertPost=1&title=" + title + "&content=" + content;

$.ajax({
    type:   'POST',
    cache:    false,
    url:      'functions.php',
    data:     data,
    success:  function( data ) {
        alert('wooo');      
    }

});
```

Then on my functions page.

```
if ($_POST['insertPost'] == true)
{
    $postTitle = $_POST['title'];
    $postContent = $_POST['content'];

    echo "Inserted";
}
else 
{
    return "No Data"; 
}

return $postData;
```

Comment: what is stored in `$postData`? Because by the look of it, you're returning a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: i've just removed it and its still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

in ajax data part(this is for POST)

```
data:{insertPost:1,title:title,content:content},
```

For GET

```
var data = "insertPost=1&title=" + title + "&content=" + content;
           ^// no & here
type:   'GET',
url:      'functions.php/'+data,
```

---

If you want to send back any data from ajax call, `return` will not work

```
return $postData;// this will not work
```

you have to echo the data in ajax call

```
echo $postData;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a POST data information as if it were GET...

change your data to:

```
data: {
   'insertPost':1,
   'title':"'+title+'",
   'content':"'+content+'"
}
```